# Wordpress advance search for function

Tags: wordpress, search

I am trying to refine my wordpress search and found the following code that I placed into my functions.php which extends the wordpress search to include all pages and posts.

```
// Search Pages AND Posts
function filter_search($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page'));
};
return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

The above code is working and includes the pages into the searches now.:)

I also want to add the following if possible:

1.) Add my wordpress categories and tags to the above code so it will return searches that include them.

2.) Exclude certain pages that I don't want to so up in the search(such as: Terms and Condition page)

I know there are plugins that do stuff like this but I thought it may be less resources on my site if I could just extend the search functions.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: use this extension:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-exclude/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

Categories are a separate taxonomy.
You'll have to create a add_filter for categories, or, just the child categories. And a function such as:

```
$categories = get_categories(‘child_of=1′);
$catlist = ”;
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
$catlist.= $cat->cat_ID.’,'; 
}
$catlist.’5′;
```

Then merge the $query, $categories vars

```
$mergedposts = array_unique( array_merge( $query, $categories ) );
```